# Queue array based implementation in C++

Tags: c++, queue

I wrote my implementation to ***Queue array based***. And I need a review for it to improve it and improve my coding skill. I also will put this implementation on my GitHub account.
*Thanks in advance.*

```
//======================================================
// Author      : Omar_Hafez
// Created     : 29 July 2022 (Friday)  5:42:53 AM
//======================================================

#include <iostream>

enum InsertStatus { FailedQueueEmpty = -1, FailedQueueFull = -2, OK = 0 };

template <class T>
class Queue {

    private:
        int MAX_SIZE;
        T* array;
        int left = 0, right = 0, elementsCount = 0;

    public:
        Queue(int MAX_SIZE = 1000000)
            : MAX_SIZE(MAX_SIZE), array((T*)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(T))) {}

        bool empty() const { 
            return elementsCount == 0; 
        }

        bool full() const { 
            return elementsCount == MAX_SIZE; 
        }

        int size() const { return elementsCount; }

        InsertStatus push(T const& t) {
            if (full()) return FailedQueueFull;
            array[right] = t;
            right = (right+1)%MAX_SIZE;
            elementsCount++;
            return OK;
        }

        InsertStatus pop() {
            if (empty()) return FailedQueueEmpty;
            left = (left+1)%MAX_SIZE;
            elementsCount--;
            return OK;
        }

        T top() const { return array[left]; }

        void clear() {
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            elementsCount = 0;
        }

        ~Queue() {
            delete(array);
            array = nullptr;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advice 1**

```
private:
    int MAX_SIZE;
    T* array;
    int left = 0, right = 0, elementsCount = 0;
```

I would clean it a bit:

```
private:
    size_t max_capacity;
    size_t head_index;
    size_t _size;
    T* array;
```

The first idea is that you should favor `size_t` over `int` for indexing and counting. The second idea here is to denote the front value by `array[head_index]` and the next tail insertion point by `array[(head_index + size) % max_capacity]`.

**Advice 2**

```
enum InsertStatus { FailedQueueEmpty = -1, FailedQueueFull = -2, OK = 0 };
```

With modern C++ you can use:

```
enum class InsertStatus { FailedQueueEmpty, FailedQueueFull, OK };
```

**Advice 3**

The method names `push` and `pop` are usually used in stacks. Since you are dealing with a FIFO queue, the more customary method names are `enqueue` and `dequeue`.

**Alternative implementation**

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
#ifndef COM_YOURCOMPANY_UTIL_ARRAY_QUEUE
#define COM_YOURCOMPANY_UTIL_ARRAY_QUEUE

#include <stdexcept>

namespace com::yourcompany::util {

template <class T>
class Queue {

private:
    size_t max_capacity;
    size_t head_index;
    size_t _size;
    T* array;

public:

    enum class OperationStatus {
        FailedQueueEmpty,
        FailedQueueFull,
        OK,
    };

    Queue(size_t max_capacity = 1_000_000)
        : max_capacity(max_capacity),
          head_index(0),
          _size(0),
          array(new T[max_capacity]) {}

    bool empty() const {
        return _size == 0;
    }

    bool full() const {
        return _size == max_capacity;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return _size;
    }

    OperationStatus enqueue(T const& t) {
        if (full()) {
            return OperationStatus::FailedQueueFull;
        }

        array[(head_index + _size++) % max_capacity] = t;
        return OperationStatus::OK;
    }

    OperationStatus dequeue() {
        if (empty()) {
            return OperationStatus::FailedQueueEmpty;
        }

        head_index = (head_index + 1) % max_capacity;
        _size--;
        return OperationStatus::OK;
    }

    T top() const { 
        if (empty()) {
            throw std::runtime_error{"top() from empty queue."};
        }

        return array[head_index]; 
    }

    void clear() {
        head_index = 0;
        size = 0;
    }

    ~Queue() {
        delete[] array;
    }
};

}; // namespace com::yourcompany::util

#endif // COM_YOURCOMPANY_UTIL_ARRAY_QUEUE
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Setting variable values in the destructor is pointless, as the object won’t exist any more as soon as the destructor returns. All you need to do is delete the array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Point. Will fix.

Answer (score 2):

- `malloc` and `delete` do not play well together. Prefer `array = new T[MAX_SIZE]` in the constructor.
- `top` happily returns something even if the queue is empty.
- `enum InsertStatus` is a misnomer. Why a *removal* operation (`pop`) returns *insert* status? A `QueueOpStatus` perhaps?
- `clear` is very optimistic. If `T` constructor allocates, you have a sure leak. `clear` must `pop` every element still in the queue. Ditto for `~Queue`.

Comment: clear is to make all the elements in the queue zero (from the user side) and we leave deallocating the array for the ~Queue

Comment: "top happily returns something even if the queue is empty"
How to fix this issue?

Comment: "do not play well together" is an understatement: it's in fact illegal to `delete` something that was not allocated using `new`, and it will crash on some platforms.

Comment: @Omar_Hafez: If `T` is anything but a plain old datatype (POD), then things here break down. You never call their constructors nor their destructors. Unless you ensure `T` is a POD, your code is broken. Using array new and array delete would solve the issue.